# Programmatically add new role to group member

Tags: 8, group

Trying to update a group membership to add an additional role, but cannot find any help on how to do this.

I want to add the role of "manager" to all owners of "client" type groups, using the following code:

```
// Get the group owner
$owner = $group->getOwner();

// Get the membership details of the owner
$membership = $group->getMember($owner);

// Get the roles of the owner
$roles = $membership->getRoles();

// Check whether the owner has manager role
if (!isset($roles['client-manager'])) {
  // No, so add the manager role to the membership
  // >>> The following doesn't work, but I hope you get the idea <<<
  $manager = new GroupRole();
  $membership->addRole($manager);
  $membership->save();
}
```

Any help or advice with this problem appreciated.

I was using hook_group_user_roles_alter(), but this has been removed in the latest release (8.x-1.0-beta5), so now need to implement a db update function to set it permanently.

Comment: I don't know group module, I'ts not clear to me what the entity types of $owner and $membership is. But if $owner is a user, then the addRole() argument excepts a user role string, not an object.

Comment: $owner is an object of class AccountInterface (ie a user).
$membership is an object of class Drupal\group\GroupMembership.
$roles is an array of objects of class Drupal\group\Entity\GroupRole.

Note that there is no "addRole" method available in GroupMembership (I wish there was). Therefore I am looking for something else that does an equivalent job.

Answer (score 4):

I was eventually able to find the correct process.  The working code follows:

```
// Get the group owner
$owner = $group->getOwner();

// Get the membership details of the owner
$membership = $group->getMember($owner);

// Get the roles of the owner
$roles = $membership->getRoles();

// Check whether the owner has manager role
if (!isset($roles['client-manager'])) {
  // No, so add the manager role to the membership
  // Get the group_content entity
  $group_content = $membership->getGroupContent();
  // Set target group role
  $group_content->group_roles->target_id = 'client-manager';
  // Save updated entity
  $group_content->save();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: My edit was reverted, however I think it's important and should be noted here. Use $group_roles->appendItem(['target_id' => $group_role]); in order to actually add role instead of overwriting all roles by new role.

Comment: Good point @Dmitriy.  However in my case, if a user has the "client-manager' role than they don't need, and probably shouldn't have any other role.

Comment: FYI, I am using the same approach, but setting/resetting the entire group_roles array with `$group_content->group_roles = $myRoleArray` since we need to update multiple roles at once